# hide div after form has been submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide a div if a span element contains a specific word. 
The issue I'm having is that the `span` only appears after a form has been submitted. I've tried to run my hide function `on click` of the submit button but this doesn't work as the span is only shown after the button has been clicked and the form submitted. I've also tried running it on `submit()` of the form but no luck either (posted the code that I've tried below).

HTML

```
    <div class=“deliveryUpsellText”>
    <p>blabla</p>
    </div>


    <ul>
      <li class=“error-msg”>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <span> Coupon Code “blabla” is not valid
         </span>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>


<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="http://dev.blabla.co.uk/cart/couponPost/" method="post">
.....

<button type="button" id="cartCoupon" title="Apply Coupon" class="button applycouponhide" onclick="discountForm.submit(false) ; " value="Apply Coupon"><span style="background:none;"><span style="background:none;">Apply</span></span></button>

</form>
```

jQuery

```
 $j('#cartCoupon').click(function(){

        if ($j(".error-msg span:contains('blabla')").length) {
            $j('.deliveryUpsellText').css({
                "display":"none"
            });
          }
        });
```

I've also tried

```
$j('#discount-coupon-form').submit(function(){
if ($j(".error-msg span:contains('blabla')").length) {
    $j('.deliveryUpsellText').css({
        "display":"none"
    });
  }
});
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: What didnt work? Any errors?

Comment: The probable reason why it does not work is that when you click the submit button / submit your form you also make a request to a server and the rest of your code runs asynchronously. Because of that, there are no spans with that text. By the time the server responds, your code already ran unsuccessfully.

What you need to do is run your code when you have received your response.

Do you have access to the code making the request / submit?

Comment: Sidenote (not a solution), you could use `$j('.deliveryUpsellText').hide()` instead of `.css({"display":"none"})`

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't hide the div.

Comment: Yeah I've got access @PetreIonescu

Comment: Do you mean by "span only appears after submit" that you get a response from the server?!

Comment: Do you submit your form with ajax? If yes, you could run your code in the success function.

EDIT: Nevermind. I see the html now.

Comment: Does the `blabla` text depend on the response from the server or is it already there at the time of submitting?

Answer (score 2):

You are using this character as quotation: ”

You should use one of these: ' or "

Also, you have this:

> onclick="discountForm.submit(false) ; "

which if the object **discountForm** is not defined, you get error before parsing the javascript part.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cartCoupon').on('click',function(){
if($('.error-msg').find("span:contains('blabla')").length > 0) {
    $('.deliveryUpsellText').hide();
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='deliveryUpsellText'>
    <p>blabla</p>
    </div>


    <ul>
      <li class="error-msg">
       <ul>
        <li>
         <span> Coupon Code “blabla” is not valid
         </span>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>


<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="http://dev.blabla.co.uk/cart/couponPost/" method="post">
.....

<button type="button" id='cartCoupon' title="Apply Coupon" class="button applycouponhide" value="Apply Coupon"><span style="background:none;"><span style="background:none;">Apply</span></span></button>

</form>
```